# Иерархическая рекурсия

Tags: postgresql, рекурсия

Есть таблица иерархии групп

где "3 уровень" самый низший, а "1 уровень" - самая высшая

Есть таблица наименований с мин и макс кол-вом, кодом наименования productid и кода группы

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=47efa1fc7c6cdfa73fd3c1646e92302f

По итогу рекурсивный запрос, начиная с самого низшего уровня, где значение min и max не NULL перебирает группы вверх по иерархии только на один уровень вверх, пока не найдет заполненное значение.
Самое верхнее значение группы, если parentid is null
Итог должен получиться вот так. Мне при помощи рекурсии нужно достать значения parentmin и parentmax

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример кода такой
prismwgroupid = '39f3ba3c-21dc-c55f-d31d-9df4cab5a33d'  - это код группы с которой начинается высчитываться

```
WITH RECURSIVE c
AS
(
select prismstock.prismwgroupid, prismwgroup.parentid, prismstock.productid, prismstock."min", prismstock."max", 1 as level 
from prismstock 
    inner join prismwgroup ON prismwgroup.id = prismstock.prismwgroupid
where prismwgroupid = '39f3ba3c-21dc-c55f-d31d-9df4cab5a33d'
 UNION ALL
    select ps.prismwgroupid, c.parentid, prismstock.productid,ps."min" as parent_min, ps."max" AS parent_max, c.level + 1 AS level
from prismstock AS ps
    INNER JOIN c ON ps.Id = c.parentid
--where prismwgroupid = '39f3ba3c-21dc-c55f-d31d-9df4cab5a33d'
    )
    SELECT *
FROM c
```

Comment: Отлично... а вопрос-то какой? *Есть таблица иерархии групп* Вы бы заменили фотографии (мы по ним не лечим) на соответствующие CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. *Итог должен получиться вот так* Итог (значения, а не форма) должен абсолютно точно соответствовать показанным исходным данным и указанным критериям отбора.

Comment: Вопрос в том, как вытащить parentmin и parentmax из группы выше, если там есть значение min или max, а если нет, то подниматься выше и выше

Comment: *где "Точки Москвы" самая низшая, а "Общее" - самая высшая* Ну если с "Общее" понятно (parentid IS NULL), то вот где бы увидеть, что "Точки Москвы" самая низшая, а? да и беда тут с деревом и вообще с исходными данными. Повторю ещё раз: Итог (значения, а не форма) должен **абсолютно точно** соответствовать **показанным исходным данным** и указанным критериям отбора. Сейчас я не вижу в принципе способа получить то, что на скриншоте, из того, что вставляется в таблицы. PS. Исходные данные лучше давать в виде [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e22d22f7de0c62de645f9fe60ebb94b5).

Comment: Исправил косяки с деревом и parentid. тогда как при помощи рекурсии вывести все min max по всем группам по иерархии?